# SQL to MDX conversion

Tags: mdx

I have this where clause in sql language:

```
where (cond1=1 or cond2=1) and cond3=1
```

How can I get this result in MDX with the slicing(condition into the where)?

```
{[cond1].&[1],[cond2].&[1]} /*and*/ {[cond3].&[1]}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a subcube:

```
    Select
    -- YOUR SELECTED MEASURES AND DIMENSIONS
    From
    (
     Select
       {[cond1].&[1],[cond2].&[1]}  on 0
      ,{[cond3].&[1]} on 1
   -- ,{more slices} on x
     From [CubeName]
    )
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use subcube expression as stated above, but this is not the only option. If you use subcube, you would increase query performance greatly (assuming the fact you don't perform crossjoins in it).

You can also use general WHERE keyword after last expression that returns cube:

```
select
{ .. } on 0,
{ .. } on 1
from (select { [Dim1].[X].allmembers } on 0)
where ([Dim2].[Y].&[Y1])
```

Or:

```
select
{ .. } on 0,
{ .. } on 1
from (select { [Dim1].[X].allmembers } on 0)
where {[DimTime].[Time].[Year].&[2001] : [DimTime].[Time].[Year].&[2015]}
```

This is applied at the end of execution, which means performance may decrease. However, if you need to apply external filter to all axis, this is the option you need.

Another way to filter member values is using tuple expressions:

```
with member LastDateSale as ( (Tail(EXISTING [DimTime].[Time].[Dates].members,1), [Measures].[ActualSales]) )
```

This will take your DimTime axis, apply external filter, get the last element from it and calculate [ActualSales] for it, if possible.